# Return attribute name Networkx Python

Tags: python, networkx

With this data:

```
G.node['node']['a']['initial'] = 100
G.node['node']['a']['final'] = 10

G.node['node']['a']['initial'] = 500
G.node['node']['b']['final'] = 15
```

I need to do the following calculation:

```
min(G.node[node]['a']['final'],G.node[node]['b']['final']) / the initial attribute of the node that has the min final value. 
= 10/100
```

I do not know who to tell python that 10 belongs to the node G.node['node']['a']. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `key` parameter of `min` function to do this.

```
min_node = min(['a', 'b'], key=lambda x: G.node['node'][x]['final'])
result = G.node['node'][min_node]['final'] / G.node['node'][min_node]['initial']
```