# Given a value, select an attribute using Networkx. Python

Tags: python, networkx

how do you tell Networkx that, given an attribute, to pick another one? More precisely, I have the following data:

```
Final_s1 = G.node[node]['s1']
Initial_s1 = G.node['a']['s1']

Final_s2 = G.node[node]['s2']
Initial_s2 = G.node['a']['s2']
```

I perform some easy calculations

```
Perf_s1 = (Final_s1 - Initial_s1)/Initial_s1
Perf_s2 = (Final_s2 - Initial_s2)/Initial_s2
```

I would like to see if there is any way of omitting the next two lines:

```
G.node[node]['Perf_s1'] = Perf_s1
G.node[node]['Perf_s2'] = Perf_s2
```

Next I find the minimum between both "performances":

```
min_node = min(['Perf_s1', 'Perf_s2'], key=lambda x: G.node[node][x])
```

This final part is what I want to learn how to program in a better way. It works, but having to add two additional attributes and a if-else statement does not look like the best thing to do.

```
if min_node == 'Perf_s1':
    Initial_Worst = G.node['a']['s1']
    Final_Worst = G.node[node]['s1']
    G.node[node]['value'] = Initial_Worst * Final_Worst
else:
    Initial_Worst = G.node['a']['s2']
    Final_Worst = G.node[node]['s2']
    G.node[node]['value'] = Initial_Worst*Final_Worst
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return attribute name Networkx Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983090/return-attribute-name-networkx-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Networkx doesn't support this kind of computation out of the box (and with reason). Nodes' attributes are simply kept as a dictionary, mapping attributes' names to values. What you're doing can be done in a more generic way with plain python code.
Here is my suggestion:

```
import random
import networkx as nx

# Generate a random graph with some values for s1 and s2:
G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(10, 0.25)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, {node: {'s1': random.randint(0, 100), 's2': random.randint(0, 100)} for node in G.nodes()})
# Choose some node 'a' (the initial node):
a = 0
# Define the metrics we are interested at:
metrics = ['s1','s2']
# For each node compute and add the value:
for node in G.nodes():
    # Compute the metrics (i.e., Perf_s1 and Perf_s2), keep in a dictionary:
    metrics_dict = {metric: (G.node[node][metric] - G.node[a][metric]) / G.node[a][metric] for metric in metrics}
    # Get the metric that minimizes the desired value (e.g., 's1'):
    arg_min = min(metrics_dict, key=metrics_dict.get)
    # Add as an attribute to the graph under 'value':
    nx.set_node_attributes(G, {node : {'value': G.node[node][arg_min] * G.node[a][arg_min]}})
```